# (Why) Does lvmraid6 need 5 drives?

Tags: lvm, software-raid, raid6, md

I'm investigating using LVMRAID instead of MD+LVM.  In my case, I'm looking at a RAID6.

As expected, [the docs](https://www.linux.org/docs/man7/lvmraid.html) say you need N+1 devices for RAID5, and a minimum of 3 drives.

[The docs](https://www.linux.org/docs/man7/lvmraid.html) say for RAID 6 you need N+2.

However, it then says that the ***minimum drives required is 5***.

In an MD RAID6, only 4 drives are required.  So if I built RAID6+LVM I'd only need 4 drives whereas, according to the docs, I'd need 5 drives for LVMRAID6.

**Does LVMRAID6 really need 5 drives?**

**If so, why does it need 5 drives rather than MDRAID6's 4 drives?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be hardcoded in the [source code](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=lvm2.git;a=blob;f=tools/lvcreate.c;h=3c22794b6f1c3cbd155df65421de21dac0bfa9fc;hb=HEAD#l528). Here a minimum of 3 stripes is the minimum, which excludes the parity disks. So that in turn is 5 disks for a RAID6.

Unfortunately the [commit message](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=lvm2.git;a=commit;f=tools/lvcreate.c;h=ea0f604e704dc8418d962e20529fd1bcddf06bb7) does not show the motivation behind the decision. You might want to ask this on the [linux-vm](https://www.redhat.com/mailman/listinfo/linux-lvm) mailing list.

Comment: +1 for reading the source code!

Comment: This is what Heinz said on the linux-lvm mailing list:  "We do have a constraint in lvm2 to require the raid6 minimum for N to be 3.

Configuring a raid6 LV (an array by MD terms) with 2 data stripes is suboptimal for performance,
because data striping is minimal in this case.  In addition, the metadata overhead is maximal
for parity, P- and Q-syndromes being half of the brutto size of the raid6 LV."